# Are empty true blocks an idiom in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just came across code that looks like this:

```
if (foo == "bar"){}else{
}
```

Is there a good reason for someone to write it that way instead of

```
if (foo != "bar") {
}
```

or am I just dealing with a raving lunatic (this is my assumption based on other things in the code).

Comment: Yes, strange. Also `!==` is preferred to `!=`.

Comment: Looks like a candidate for the DailyWTF blog

Comment: I can't say i have not done that before....

Comment: At our agency, we often work with 3rd parties to collaborate on projects. I've occasionally received terrible code (projects loading the entire jQueryUI library to use one method within it one single time, poorly optimized loops, etc.), and I've got no qualms in sending it back to the provider. My stance is that I'm not attaching my company name to poor-quality engineering if I can avoid it. From your "assumption based on other things in the code" it sounds like this might be a situation where you need to call the 3rd party's Tech Director and talk code quality with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of my developers wrote code that way, I'd throw it back at them with a reprimand and a copy of "Javascript: The Good Parts." I can't think of a single good reason for doing that.

Also, they should have written their comparison as `if (foo === "bar")`. Much better practice.

**Edit a year and a half later:**

Out of boredom I knocked together a jsperf just to see if there was any noticeable performance difference between the two methods shown in the OP, and *[SPOILER WARNING]* no there isn't.

http://jsperf.com/empty-blocks-in-if-else-statement

Comment: As a dynamic programmer with mostly Perl experience, I have to ask, why should I care about the type of `foo`?  If it coerces into `"bar"` then it is `"bar"` as far as my purposes go.  I can see how it might be useful in other scenarios, but why should I use `===` as a general rule?

Comment: In this specific case using `==` is fine, but the rules around how `==` and `!=` coerce values of different types have so many irregularities and inconsistencies (`0=='0'` resolves as true, but  `false=='false'` resolves as false, for example) that it's a common best practice to just never use them.

Answer (score 11):

**[Edit]**

There is no such convention in the JavaScript community.  This is just bad code.

**[Original "Answer" Below]**

I prefer to use the following syntax when I am leaving a project:

```
if (foo == "bar") {               /* 100 or so spaces */ } else {
}
```

The `} else {` segment is hopefully obscured off screen by text editors so that the code does the exact opposite of what it seems. This way I can ensure that the remaining development team curses my name and would never consider me for future development or support.  =D

Comment: `+1` just for the evility (is that a word?) of it ^_^

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why JavaScript code should be different in this respect from any C-heritage language. I've not encountered this idiom before, and I really don't like it. I need to mentally parse the thing twice to make sure I've understood.

The only analogue I can think of is an empty default in a switch statement,with a copious comment to say "I thought about this and it's just fine."

Comment: Actually, JavaScript is heritage of C, Scheme, Java, Perl, Python, Self. Mostly Scheme self and Java however.

Comment: There's a lineage through Java, C++ and C - of course there are other ancestors too. The if () {} else {} sure looks like C!

Answer (score 3):

I have done it before.

This is when I *might* want to add some debug statements later.

Yes sure he could have done

```
if (foo != "bar"){
   //something
}else{}
```

But isn't that just the same thing?

---

Back to the code you saw.

So what the programmer probably did is:

```
if (foo == "bar"){}
else{/*something*/}
```

Then later on when he wanted to add some debug information into the 1st part he would.
The logic still works and it is not flawed in the least bit. (in my opinion)

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but in that case the developer really should have put a comment inside the empty first part denoting a debug statement or some other code to come, if only to save the sanity of any other developers that might view his code in the meantime.

Comment: @Scottie, we do not know what the situation was in the OP's case, he could have been taking over for a programmer who was let go and did not think that others would scrutinize his or her code.

Comment: Fair point, I'm definitely making assumptions with my statement.

Comment: anyone care to explain the `-1`? looks nice next to this answer :-D

Comment: It's not from me, so I +1'd you to compensate (which I should have done anyways, since I agreed with your answer).

Comment: In this situation, it is all new code handed off to us by a third party.

Answer (score 2):

It's confusing for two reasons. The syntax is confusing because he's evaluating foo == bar just to do ... nothing? It seems unnecessary not to use the syntax you suggested. Visually it's also confusing because the empty block and the if evaluation are on one line, so if I were reading this code later I might gloss over things and assume the statement read as

```
if (foo == "bar"){
}
```

Which is the exact opposite of the code's intention. One possible explanation for this is that the programmer intended to go back and implement some code for foo == bar, but either didn't or forgot to do so.

My vote is for lunatic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to do that.

On a side note, however, keep in mind that with loops there are sometimes cases where an empty block may be acceptable:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; document.getElementById("box" + i).value != ""; i++) { }
// do something with i
```

Comment: I'd just write `for(i = 0; document.getElementById("box" + i).value != ""; i++);` with a semi-colon. Instead of an empty block...

Comment: I prefer to use a semicolon instead of an empty block, e.g. `for(...);`.

Comment: Using a loop for a side effect is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to write chained `if`'s like this:

```
if (a) {
} else if (b) {
    // do something
} else if (c) {
    // do something
} else if (d) {
    // do something
}
```

Rather than:

```
if (!a) {
    if (b) {
        // do something
    } else if (c) {
        // do something
    } else if (d) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This makes the code more neat IMO.

Does it make sense?

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @BoltClock: This was an example of an empty block that is probably acceptable. I wrote this because many people seem to think empty blocks should be avoided in all cases.